# Ignoring CocoaPods libraries in the repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore, cocoapods

I have a repository.

I suppose that I don't need to save all pods library in my repo, because I can install them at any time using `pod install` command.

But when I run `pod install` the message bellow appears:

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.

Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'

as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I run git status and see:

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is my gitigonre:

```
# OS X ignores
.DS_Store

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes

# Xcode
build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside

Pods
```

So the question is how to store only information in Pods file and don't store libraries in the repo, because we have access to download them at any time while cocoa pods server works.

Comment: When was the last time you successfully ran a pod install?

Comment: @PeterFoti I don't know maybe last month =) are there any new tricks?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CocoaPods master spec got all sorts of messed up a little over a week ago. For that reason you're going to have to delete your local copy and then follow their instructions to set it up again.

The link to their blog that discusses the issue: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

The command for getting back up and running:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
```